# el contenido de mi fichero de texto se borra cuando hago print("ARCHIVO".readlines())

Tags: python

Las variables por si hay algo mal

```
# FILE #

File_Select = input("FILE DIR / FILE NAME> ")
File = open(File_Select, "r+")
FileA = open(File_Select, "a")
FileC = open(File_Select, "w")
File_Mode = input("RUN File / READ File / WRITE File / CLEAR File [FRun][FRead][FWrite][FClear] >>> ")
```

aqui estan las funciones que se ejecutan al segundo input que es que haras con el codigo como escribir leer borrar o run que es algo experimental y no interfiere porque esta en otro archivo por eso el [FRun]

```
#   FMODE FUNC  #

def READ(FILE):
    try:
        with open(FILE) as File:
            print(File.readlines())
    except:
        print("Hay problemas con el nombre del archivo")
    

def ADD():
    FWRITE = input(">>> ")
    FileA.writelines(FWRITE)
    print("FILE CONTENT ADDED:", FWRITE)
    FileA.close()

def Clear():
    FileC.writelines("CONTENT CLEARED")
    print("FILE CONTENT CLEAR")
    FileC.close()
```

detecto que quiere hacer el usuario y ejecuto la funcion

```
#   FMode MANAGER   #

if File_Mode.lower() == "frun": #ignorar
    File_check()

if File_Mode.lower() == "fread":
    READ(File_Select)

if File_Mode.lower() == "fwrite":
    ADD()

if File_Mode.lower() == "fclear":
    Clear()
```

Comment: es muy raro, he probado tu codigo, exactamente despues de que la funcion fuese definida la llame, el programa imprimio el archivo y su contenido estaba dentro, en que version programaste eso?

Comment: uso python 3.9.6 quieres el codigo completo ese es el fragmento que deberia estar mal por eso no pongo todo lo otro, ahora tambien el input elimina el contenido del archivo 

Comment: si, hazme el favor de colocarme el codigo completo, asi puedo hacer mejor el debugging y ayudarte mas facil

Comment: listo dime que ves mal y corrigo de mientras sigo en la funcion experimental  

Comment: Estas abriendo el mismo archivo en modo read, append y write ... **al mismo tiempo** Eso no tiene ninguna lógica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debería funcionar al llamar la función, aunque la línea Archivo en la función no es necesaria, pero te aconsejo algo:

```
SELECCION_ARCHIVO = (input("Nombre del archivo: ")) #Uso un input para la selección de archivo


def LEER_Archivo(arch):
```

no opero con el nombre todavía y al crear la función le paso un parámetro que será el nombre del archivo

```
try:
    with open(arch) as Archivo:
        print(Archivo.readlines())
except:
    print("Hay problemas con el nombre del archivo")
```

dentro de la función uso try y except para capturar algún posible error, como que no exista el archivo o esté mal el nombre

y lo manejo con with ya que por defecto trae el cerrar archivo por si me olvido de declararlo

y cuando lo abro no uso el modificador 'r' ya que viene por defecto y si bien no está mal es una redundancia.

```
LEER_Archivo(SELECCION_ARCHIVO)
```

por último llamo a la función pasándole el nombre obtenido con el input.

modifico lo anterior porque cambiaron el sentido de la pregunta original y lo aplico a la nueva.

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
File_Select = input("FILE DIR / FILE NAME> ")
File_Mode = input("RUN File / READ File / WRITE File / CLEAR File [FRun][FRead][FWrite][FClear] >>> ").lower()


def Modo(archivo,forma):
    modos={"fread": "r+",'fwrite':"a","fclear":"w"}
    modo = modos.get(forma)
    if forma:
        try:
            with open(archivo,modo) as File:
                if forma == "fread":
                    print(File.readlines())
                if forma == "fwrite":
                    ADD(File)
                if forma == "fclear":
                    Clear(File)

        except:
            print("Hay problemas con el nombre del archivo")
def ADD(ar):
    FWRITE = input(">>> ")
    ar.writelines(FWRITE)
    print("FILE CONTENT ADDED:", FWRITE)
    
def Clear(ar):
    ar.writelines("CONTENT CLEARED")
    print("FILE CONTENT CLEAR")

Modo(File_Select, File_Mode)
```

más de lo mismo, pero usando funciones que fueron agregadas y no elimino solo para tratar de respetar la lógica de la pregunta.

Comment: me funciono una vez luego de eso cada vez que se introduce al input el nombre del archivo borra el contendio

Comment: ahhh, pero ahora cambiaste los datos de la pregunta original.

Comment: agregué contenido a mi respuesta anterior en base a todos los cambios que hiciste, si haces más cambios intentá generar una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Gracias pero ya la resolví gracias por tu aportación

Answer (score 1):

he descubierto el error que hay en tu codigo, al parecer al principio, denominas unas variables llamadas FileA, FileC y File

Cuando eso es ejecutado, al crear la variable File, Python recrea el archivo,
asi que he quitado todo esas variables del principio, y las he denominado en las funciones donde son necesarias, su nuevo codigo es este:

```
File_Select = input("FILE DIR / FILE NAME> ")
File_Mode = input("RUN File / Read File / WRITE File / CLEAR File [FRun] [FRead] [FWrite] [FClear]: ")
def READ(FILE):
try:
    with open(FILE) as File:
      print(File.readlines())
  except:
    print("Hay problemas con el nombre de archivo")
def ADD():
  FileA = open(File_Select, "a")
  FWRITE = input(">>> ")
  FileA.writelines(FWRITE)
  print("FILE CONTENT ADDED:", FWRITE)
  FileA.close()
def Clear():
  FileC = open(File_Select, "w")
  FileC.writelines("CONTENT_CLEARED")
  print("file content clear")
  FileC.close()
if File_Mode.lower() == "frun":
  pass
elif File_Mode.lower() == "fwrite":
  ADD()
elif File_Mode.lower() == "fread":
  READ(File_Select)
elif File_Mode.lower() == "fclear":
  Clear()
```

SOlamente acuerdese de colocarle las sangrias de nuevo, es decir, poner bien los tabuladores, porque el programa de escritura de Stack Overflow no funciona bien

Comment: hice  debug i vaya mira lo que habia dentro del archivo de texto Print>GRACIAS CANAL PC PD: la caracteristica experimental usa Read y write simplemente le agrego File = FileSelect, "r+" para leer y escribir ? porque es un if del texto si contiene cierta cosa ejecuta tal cosa y sino lo añade :) (empeze python hace una semana los errores eran muy comunes no?)